Vulnerability -Server-Side Request Forgery. Make a DNS lookup to an external domain
Description: A web server (IIS) will make a DNS lookup to an external domain if it is
included in the HTTP line of a GET request. Exploitation of this vulnerability
does not require authentication.
Impact: The application server’s IP address is exposed, which increases the
likelihood that it could be attacked directly and reduces the effectiveness of
load balancers as a security control.
Recommended Remediation: Ensure that arbitrary domains included in the HTTP line of requests to xxx.xxx.com do not trigger lookups. Requests should be of an expected formation to be processed.
Is there any setting in IIS that can be done to fix this issue?

You can try to use the Request Filtering feature page to configure filtering rules for your website. web request filtering let you restrict protocol and content behavior. more information you can refer to this link: Request Filtering.
